Types of karma - stable/unstable?
I came across the terms 'stable' and 'unstable karma'. I tried to find  the meaning through Google, but without any luck.
Can anyone explain their meaning?

You are asking, I believe, about dridha karma and adridha karma. These are often translated into English as "stable/unstable karma"—reasonably, considering that dridha translates to things like 'fixed,' 'firm,' or 'steady,' while adridha translates to 'not firm,' 'inconstant,' or, more extrapolatively, 'not decided.'
These terms are used in astrology. The Prasna Marga outlines the meanings of these words; I've used the translation edited by Bangalore Venkata Raman below:

103:
The nature of the evil Karma
will be Dridha or Adhridha according as the
indicative planet is in the house of the Moon or
the Sun. When planets are favourably placed,
they indicate fruition of good Karma, otherwise
that of evil Karma. The mental, verbal or bodily
nature of the Karma is revealed by the position
of a malefic planet in the 5th, 2nd or 10th
house.
Explanation:
Man suffers from misfortunes in the shape of loss of welat, humiliation, loss of name, death of kith and kin, disease, etc., as a result of evil Karma done in his previous life. This Karma is either Dridha—intentional and deliberate—or Aridha—accidental or unintentional. In either case the consequence is felt.

Some examples are provided in the text. For brevity, I'll assume that you're familiar with the terms kayaka, manasika, and vachaka. If not, check the linked translation, which does include some more clarification. (It also explains the astrological aspect more in detail.)

Deliberately insulting, assaulting, or harboring evil thoughts towards one's elders is dridha, vachaka, and dridha kayaka.
However, accidentally causing harm, or anger exploding as a result of a "slip of tongue" is adridha manasika and adridha kayaka.

Note that there's retribution in both, for—significantly—the "aggrieved party" is still affected negatively.

Thank you. Your answer really made me understand the terms.

@bluejay05 - I'm glad to hear it. I hope you stick around and ask more interesting questions (like this one)!
